# Python Function and closure

Tags: python-3.x, function, closures

```
def html_tag(tag):

    def wrap_text(msg):
        print(f'{tag}  {msg}  {tag}')

    return wrap_text

html_tag('Hi')
print(html_tag)
check_h1 = html_tag('Hi')
print(check_h1)
```

CONSOLE RETURNS

```
<function html_tag at 0x108492b00>
<function html_tag.<locals>.wrap_text at 0x1085b0280>
```

SO I KNOW THAT FIRST LINE OF CONSOLE FUNCTION WAS STORED IN COMPUTER'S MEMORY, BUT WHAT HAPPENED TO THAT `'Hi'` ARGUMENT IN `html_tag` FUNCTION.
ALSO IN 2ND LINE OF CONSOLE I GUESS `'Hi'` WAS STORED AS ARGUMENT OF `tag` PARAMETER, BUT WHY THAT DID NOT OCCUR WITH `html_tag('Hi')`?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that once you are referencing the wrap_text function and once the html_tag function.
With the use of

```
html_tag('Hi')
```

you do call the function and receive the wrap_text functon, you do however never store the returend result. if you change

```
html_tag('Hi')
print(html_tag)
```

to

```
my_html_tag = html_tag('Hi')
print(my_html_tag)
```

you would get the expected result.
When you simply call

```
print(html_tag)
```

you tell python to print the html_tag function, which is not influenced by you calling it earlier via

```
html_tag('Hi')
```